# How to Convert a String formatted Big number to Number?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Suppose

```
String num = "14151841515451321511151545"
```

I want to convert this to

```
number = 14151841515451321511151545
```

I need to convert to Number to compare with another String formatted number like

```
String num2 = "7845141651641616111"
```

How to do it? Is there any String method to compare with long string formatted number?

I tried `Long.parseLong()`, but It is giving `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Look up `BigInteger`.

Comment: If one string is shorter, it's smaller.  If the same length, then a string comparison will work.

Comment: @TimRoberts Don’t rely on that. It depends on signs and leading zeroes. Do parse into `BogInteger` so the reader needs not worry whether you have covered all cases.

Comment: Use `new BigInteger(num).compareTo(new BigInteger(num2))`. Gave 1 on my Java 18 meaning that `num` is strictly greater than `num2` (which it indeed is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings compare character "strings" and not numbers, as their name implies.

Also "7845141651641616111" is too large for an integer.

Try:

```
String num = "14151841515451321511151545"
BigInteger number = new BigInteger(num);
String num2 = "7845141651641616111"
BigInteger number2 = new BigInteger(num2);
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html for comaperTo(...), equals(...), etc.